# Starting multiple programs in one command

Tags: command-line

How can I start multiple programs using one line of command? This is what I have so far:

```
cmd /C "C:\Program Files\PeerBlock\peerblock.exe" && "C:\Program Files\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe"
```

I do not want uTorrent to start if PeerBlock is not started.

(I need this for Launchy's runner plugin.)

Answer (score 3):

Make a batch file - call it Launchy.bat or something and add all your commands there.

Comment: In this case, add `start` before the commands if they are not console commands, otherwise, the batchfile will wait for each process to exit before continuing.

Comment: +1 for avoiding the dark abyss of "correct quoting" on Windows